# Css menu issue - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, topmenu

I added another category item and now **"Contact us"** is below that section
[image]

I would like to know how can I **extend the menu section** so that everything remains in one row. This is the website  https://usengineproduction.com
my css

Comment: It's seems like this problem is solved if this problem solved by one of below answer you can accept that or you can post your own answer to help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, i haven't this problem Without any modification
[image]
However, you can reduce the padding and the police like this:

in custommenu line 8:

```
div.menu {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

custommenu line 5:

```
.header-menu {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

custommenu ligne 147 @screen and (max-width: 1200px):

```
div.menu {
    margin: 0 8px;
}
```

It becomes like this: 
[image]

Comment: this method worked

Comment: Cool, you can now validate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

how do you want to fix it? 
If you move it up you might have alignment issues with the rest of the page.
You can make the .container class wider.
I saw that it's

```
    width: 1170px;
```

You can increase that.

Answer (score 0):

You must change this css (custommenu.css:147)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px)
div.menu {
    margin: 0 8px;
}
```

Your header will be shown on this way.

[image]

Also, I have checked that on screens with width of 1136px, your header is shown wrong. On this way.

[image]

You must show the mobile header in this resolution and not in 1135px.